# Autocomplete PDF from Excel and print multiple times

Tags: excel, pdf, automation

I'm looking for a way to populate a PDF file from Excel and print for the purpose of prices to put in used cars.

So I would have a list of registration numbers and the prices for each car and the PDF sheet needs to have the price copied over and the registration and then print close and repeat on the next line in the excel sheet.

Can this be done?

Comment: Well, the raw info is ALL excel for other tasks, so not wrong, convenience....anyone else?

Comment: Ok - what's the easier way? As I can move the excel data the pricing template would be trickier.

Comment: Well, I don't have a method that's why I'm here, asking if it's possible.. I'm really not sure that it is